# Can map contain class objects or class objects?

Tags: c++, class, stl, dictionary

Can map contain class objects or  class objects?

I think key should be a built-in primary type, its associated data value can a class or class object.

For example,

```
stl::map<int , myClass> myMap;
myMap.insert(pair<int , myClass>);
```

Is it possible for key to be a self-defined class ?

```
stl::map<myClass , int> myMap;
```

if yes, how to sort the key ?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'class objects *or* class objects'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `map`'s key can be anything that has default constructor, supports copying and comparison. By default, `map` compares keys with `std::less` comparator, which calls `operator <`. So, if you define `operator <` for your class, or provide custom comparison class for the map, you can use it with `map`, `set` etc.